# Search Confusion

Tags: email, search, search-results, custom-search, option

I do not understand how to run searches & be sure that anyone who does not have an email address or has opted out of emails in any way is not included.

How do I segment the database, to run searches to find the right people?

Anyone have some directions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to exclude all of those email options at once for an export or something I would search up those people, put them in a group, and exclude the group from your searches.

To search up that group of people I would use search builder (Search>Search Builder in the main CiviCRM menu) with the following settings:

Contacts: Email: Primary: Is Empty
*Also Include*
Contacts: On-Hold: Primary: > 1
*Also Include*
Contacts: Do Not Email: = 1
*Also Include*
Contacts: No Bulk Emails (User Opt Out): = 1

If you are using civiMail the system should not let you actually send mails to any of the groups described, even if they are included in your target groups (just as it de-duplicates for you when you send to multiple groups). You can see this when you look at the "estimated recipients" on the right hand side in civiMail is lower than the actual sum count of your target groups.

Comment: I am not using CiviMail